# Entity Framework code first. Adding 2 references to a parent creates 3 foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Have a code first Entity Framework application here.
I need to add another reference to my parent class (**User**) in the **Journal** class .
I already have User, now want to add FieldResponsible of a class **User**

```
public class User
{
   public List<Journal> Journals { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the child I have:

```
public class Journal
{
     ..other fields

   public int UserID { get; set; }       

    [ForeignKey("UserID")] //this was added to show its not working either
    public User User { get; set; }

     //  ..now the field i'm adding
    public int? FieldResponsibleID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FieldResponsibleID")]
    public User FieldResponsible { get; set; }
}
```

Now after I recreate my database I get:

```
[UserID]             INT            NOT NULL,
[FieldResponsibleID] INT            NULL,
[User_UserID]        INT            NULL,

CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Journals_dbo.Users_User_UserID] FOREIGN KEY ([User_UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Journals_dbo.Users_FieldResponsibleID] FOREIGN KEY ([FieldResponsibleID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Journals_dbo.Users_UserID] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: your question is not very clear ... can you mention which is parent class, child and what key your are trying to add ?

Comment: Parent is User. Child is Journal. Trying to add 2 references to User in Journal. There was one before (User), now I'm trying to add another one (FieldResponsible) which also of class User

Comment: You need to associate `User.Journals` with one of the two `Journal.User` properties, otherwise EF assumes a 3rd relationship. For instance, decorate `Journals` property with `[InverseProperty("User")]`.

Comment: Hi Ivan. That worked for me. If you post it as an answer I will accept. Thanks.